# Nested component two-way binding

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on a small blazor server-side page and two-way binding isn't working as I'd expect. I've distilled what I'm seeing to a basic example below:

```cs
// CreateBill.razor

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnSubmit="CreateBillSubmit">

    <SpecialInstructions Instructions="@Model.SpecialInstructions" />

</EditForm>

@code {
    private CreateBillViewModel? Model { get;set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() => Model = new CreateBillViewModel()
    {
        BillDate = DateTime.Today,
        SpecialInstructions = "Default Instructions",
    };

    private async Task CreateBillOnSubmit(EditContext arg)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);

        Console.WriteLine("Submitted");
    }
}

// SpecialInstructions.razor
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="header-title">Special Instructions <span class="text-danger">*</span></h4>
            <p class="sub-header">
                Special instructions for the driver and consignee.
            </p>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <textarea 
                class="form-control" 
                id="special-instructions" 
                rows="3" 
                placeholder="Please enter any special instructions for the driver" 
                @bind-value=Instructions @bind-value:event="oninput"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string? Instructions { get; set; }
}

// CreateBillViewModel.cs
public class CreateBillViewModel
{
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }
    public string SpecialInstructions { get; set; }
}
```

#### What's working

- The textbox renders and is preloaded with "Default Instructions"

#### What's not working

- When I edit the textbox, change focus, and click the submit button, the new text is NOT reflected in the `EditContext` object of the submitted form.

[image: The SpecialInstructions field has not reflected the change I made in the UI]

I'm wondering if I am using incorrect directives or something to map the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build binding into your component.

Here's your `SpecialInstructions` refactored as basic edit control.

I'm assuming you're using Net7.0.  If you're still on 6.0, I'll refactor the code for you.

The text area now receives it's value from `Instructions` and calls `ChangeInstructionsAsync` when the value changes.  This invokes the EventCallback `InstructionsChanged`.

I've included the `InstructionsExpression` so you can display error messages within your component.

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

<div class="col-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="header-title">Special Instructions <span class="text-danger">*</span></h4>
            <p class="sub-header">
                Special instructions for the driver and consignee.
            </p>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <textarea class="form-control"
                          id="special-instructions"
                          rows="3"
                          placeholder="Please enter any special instructions for the driver"
                @bind:get="Instructions" @bind:set="this.ChangeInstructionsAsync" @bind:event="oninput"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Instructions { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> InstructionsChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string?>>? InstructionsExpression { get; set; }


    private async Task ChangeInstructionsAsync(string? value)
    {
        await this.InstructionsChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

And then your edit page.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnSubmit="CreateBillOnSubmit">

    <SpecialInstructions @bind-Instructions="@Model.SpecialInstructions" />

</EditForm>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @Model.SpecialInstructions
</div>

@code {
    private CreateBillViewModel Model { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized() => Model = new CreateBillViewModel()
        {
            BillDate = DateTime.Today,
            SpecialInstructions = "Default Instructions",
        };

    private async Task CreateBillOnSubmit(EditContext arg)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5);

        Console.WriteLine("Submitted");
    }
}
```

You can "Normalize" the component by renaming `Instructions` to `Value`, and changing the bind names.

Comment: Thanks! I am using .net 8 RC1 so this worked perfectly. Only snag was my `SpecialInstruction` component didn't reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` so the data binds didn't work initially. However, once I added the using statement, it started working. Here's more details on the binding process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: You can learn a lot by reviewing the source code for the standard Blazor Edit controls here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms